# In the Big Bang theory which came first, the vacuum or matter?

Tags: vacuum, big-bang, matter

Simply what is our best estimation of what came first in the the first fraction of time of the BB? Was it the vacuum and then matter popped out from violent quantum vacuum fluctuations or matter then after matter diluted making vacuum?

Comment: Our best understanding of it is in terms of quantum field theory, which simultaneously postulates the spacetime and fields on it, and "matter" is just a specific field state. QFT also predicts an expanding space can create particles. See e.g. Sec. II [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.02444.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about "first fraction of time after the big bang", it's important to define what instant exactly you call "the big bang". It's also important to realize that when the "fraction" is extremely small, we reach energies beyond our present understanding of the theory, and where quantum gravity becomes important, so at best we have a partial understanding of the situation.

Anyway, "matter" as we know it - leptons (electrons, etc.) and hadrons (protons and neutrons, both composed of quarks) - could only appear once the universe expanded enough, and the energy density became low enough, for the earlier symmetry between all those things to break (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_unification_energy).  But even more importantly, when the universe was extremely dense, we believe that there were roughly equal number of particles and anti-particle, which were at a steady state between colliding, being "annihilated" into radiation (photons) and then the photons convert again into particle-anti-particle pairs, and vice versa. You could only start talking about "matter" once there began to be some excess of one type of matter (let's call it "particles") over the other (anti-particles) - in our universe this excess seems to be roughly 1e-8 - i.e., we have roughly 1e8 the number of photons (the result of annihilations) to letons. You can read how we think this might have happened (we don't have a definitive theory yet) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leptogenesis.

Another thing that we believe that happened before "matter" appeared in the universe was inflation: Particles called "inflatons" caused the universe to expand exponentially, and any ordinary matter particles, if there were any before the inflation, would have been completely diluted away. When inflated ended (at least in our observable patch of the universe), there would have been no particles left - just energy. All the particles would have been created later from the energy, in the processes I described above.

So all in all, I would say the answer: particles came after the big bang, not before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this initial state you describe with equal number of particles with antiparticles reminds more or less to the definition of the ZPE vacuum and its quantum fluctuations in locked cycle of constant annihilation and pair creation. So maybe it was actually of phase of a ZPE vacuum but with much larger and intense quantum fluctuations ZPF and maybe the average equilibrium ZPE of this genesis vacuum was not that low as today? Meaning the vacuum energy density (dark energy) at that time would have been much higher leading to rapid inflation of the vacuum.

Comment: Yes, sort of. The theory of inflation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology) - suggests that there was a high potential energy of the inflaton field, which when inflation ended by rolling down this potential hill, resulted in lots of energy (much more than the ZPE of today's universe) that could be used to create particle-anti-particle pairs. But they always come in pairs unless some process ("Leptogenesis") can some break the time symmetry of pair production and annihilation.